# Denseness of a particular sequence space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> For $a\in\mathbb R$, let $h_a$ be the Hilbert space of sequences defined by
> $$ h_a=\left\{(x_n):\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(1+n^2)^a|x_n|^2<\infty\right\}$$
> and inner product $\langle(x_n),(y_n)\rangle_a=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(1+n^2)^ax_n\overline{y_n}$.
>
> **Prove that if $b>a$ then $h_b$ is dense in $h_a$.**

Attempt: So far, I have shown that $b>a$ then $h_b\subset h_a$. However, I don't have a clear idea on how to show that $h_b$ is dense in $h_a$. Probably I need to show that for any element in $h_a$ there is a sequence in $h_b$ converging to it; beyond that, I'm stuck.

Any help or guidance on this question would be appreciated greatly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n) \in h_a$. Let $y_n=x_n$ for $|n| \leq N$ and $y_n=0$ for $|n| >N$. Then $(y_n) \in h_b$. Now the norm of $(x_n-y_n)$ in $h_a$ is $\sqrt {\sum_{|n|>N} (1+n)^{a}|x_n|^{2}}$. Recall that of  series $\sum c_n$ of non-negative numbers is convergent than $\sum_{|n|>N|} c_n \to 0$ as $ N \to \infty$. Hence, given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N$ such that $\|(x_n)-(y_n)\| <\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you sir for the illuminating response. The result is clear to me now. Would you have a moment to look at a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3908221/invertible-map-on-a-particular-sequence-space)?