# Translation mapping on a Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Denote the unit circle by $S^1$, so that $2\pi$-periodic functions can be viewed as functions on $S^1$. The Sobolev space $H^k(S^1)$ is defined by
>
> $$ H^k(S^1)=\left\{f\in L^2(S^1):\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(1+n^2)^k|(Ff)_n|^2<\infty\right\},$$
> where $F:L^2(S^1)\to\ell_2(\mathbb Z)$ is the Fourier map such that
> $$ (Ff)_n=\langle f(x),(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{inx}\rangle_{L^2}=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx. $$
> For $c\in\mathbb R$, define the translation map $t_c:C(S^1)\to C(S^1)$ by $(t_cf)(x)=f(x+c)$.
>
> 1. Prove that $t_c$ extends to a continuous linear map on $L^2(S^1)$, and that maps from $H^k(S^1)$ into itself when $k\geq0$.
> 2. Prove that if $(x_n)$ is a nonzero real sequence with $\lim x_n=0$ and $f\in H^1(S^1)$, then $(1/x_n)(t_{x_n}f-f)\to f'$ in $L^2(S^1)$.
> 3. Prove that if $f\in L^2(S^1)$ and $(1/x_n)(t_{x_n}f-f)$ is bounded in $L^2(S^1)$ for some sequence $(x_n)\to0$, then $f\in H^1(S^1)$.

**What I've done so far:** I think I can show statement (1). First I show $t_c$ is linear, which is easy, and then I can show that $\|t_c\|=\|f\|$, so it is bounded. Because $\overline{C(S^1)}=L^2(S^1)$, I conclude that $t_c$ uniquely extends to a continuous linear map on $L^2(S^1)$. Then, for any $f\in H^k(S^1)$ I know that $\sum(1+n^2)^k|(Ff)_n|^2<\infty$. Also, $(F(t_cf))_n=e^{inc}(Ff)_n$, so
$$
\sum(1+n^2)^k|(F(t_cf))_n|^2=\sum(1+n^2)^k|e^{inc}(Ff)_n|^2=\sum(1+n^2)^k|(Ff)_n|^2<\infty.
$$
This means that $t_c$ is a map from $H^k(S^1)\to H^k(S^1)$.

I am stuck on statements (2) and (3). Geometrically, I can see that statement 2 is a finer and finer approximation of the derivative - however, I am having trouble formalizing this notion. Any help on (2) and (3) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!